# Check a varchar column if it is a number or not

Tags: sql-server

So I have a column which is of `varchar` datatype and user may enter value in in something like 100000,-1000000 and so on. I need to validate if that column has numbers or not

-10000 is valid

100.32 is valid

> 100,000 is invalid

So I have come down to use

`select * from mytable where isnumeric(replace([mycol],',','*')) <>1`

or

`select * from mytable where TRY_CAST([mycol] as FLOAT) IS NULL`

I am able to get my job done by these 2 methods but I would want to know which is efficient. Or is there a better a to get the job done

Comment: Do not use `ISNUMERIC()` read the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You should use `TRY_CAST`, which has the ability to handle things like locale (e.g. PI is `3.14159` in the US, but `3,14159` in Europe).

Comment: So are commas being present the only example of an invalid value? If that's the case, or there's only a couple of invalid styles and it's safe to assume anything else is valid, you could just check for those examples first.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a data is either castable into the specified cast or not using `try_cast()` as shown below.

It will return `null` if not castable into the specified cast you are trying.

```
create table MyTable (Data varchar(20))
insert into MyTable values
('-10000'), ('100.32'), ('100,000')

Select Data
 Data
 , try_Cast(Data as decimal) DataInDecimal
 , try_cast(Data as int) DataInInteger
from MyTable
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a0e0088c4b02291f6492419de1be7c5) demo.